# Creating PDF out of custom components in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jspdf, html2canvas, react-pdf

**Requirement:**

> I have to export a dashboard into PDF, this dashboard contains multiple tabs. Each tab has data that is dynamically fetched only once the tab is clicked on. Requirement is that all the tabs data should get exported into a pdf having multiple pages.

**Methods Tried**

> 1. Tried **html2canvas** and then saved the same into **jsPDF**. Got stuck as I needed multiple divs to be exported and saved into multiple pages. [If this can be fixed, well and good]

> 2. Tried **React-Pdf**, Apparently I couldn't use my dynamic tables/reports in this. so another dead end.

Just need one dashboard which contains multiple tabs to be exported into a pdf.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the data is loaded when a specific tab is opened.
Would it be possible to create another page where you add multiple dashboards, each with a separate tab open, and then create the pdf?

Comment: That can be done, But please let me know the further steps as to how multiple divs can be added into different pages